# MVC 3 duplicate area name on Ajax request

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having a problem which is really boring me. I have an ajax request on an specific area which return me a 404 error and when I look to the call, the Url is as the following one: `localhost/Tracker/%E2%80%8B/Tracker/TrackerMap/GetAreas` and the one i'm expecting to receive is the following: `localhost/Tracker/TrackerMap/GetAreas`. The funny part of all is when i look to the html and I get the right Url, so i really don't know what is going on and why I'm having this problem only in this area.

The ajax code i'm using is the following:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '​@Url.Action("GetAreas")',
            data: {
                areaKey: $('#TrackerParentAreaKey').val(),
            },
            success: function (e) {
                ...
            }
        });
```

And the Html after rendering is the following:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '​/Tracker/TrackerMap/GetAreas',
            data: {
                areaKey: $('#TrackerParentAreaKey').val(),
            },
            success: function (e) {
                ...
            }
        });
```

Comment: What Fiddler ( www.fiddler2.com ) says about it?

Comment: this is what fiddler shows:
# Result Protocol Host URL Body Caching Content-Type Process Comments Custom 
97 404 HTTP localhost /Tracker/%E2%80%8B/Tracker/TrackerMap/GetAreas 5.015 private text/html; charset=utf-8 chrome:5200

Comment: Can you make a screenshot please and upload to imgur.com?

Comment: sure, http://i.imgur.com/TxImyHh.png

Comment: I think you have to try to download debug version of jQuery and modify ajax call to display url property (via console.log or alert).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the answer is more simple than we expect. The problem was solved converting the file encode, for some reason it was not on UTF8 Encode, and that is why the url was like that.